# eslint проверяет json файлы

Tags: javascript, eslint

Прописал команду в `package.json`:

```
"lint": "eslint server/src/* public/src/* --ext .ts --ext .tsx"
```

Запускаю её и она выводит мне ошибку:

> public\src\tsconfig.json
>
> 2:13  error  Parsing error: ';' expected
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Зачем и почему eslint лезет в json, если ему явно были указаны типы файлов `.ts` и '.tsx'?

Answer (score 0):

Опция --ext обрабатывается, только если не указана конкретная директория.

Документация: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface

> Note: --ext is only used when the arguments are directories. 
>   If you use glob patterns or file names, then --ext is ignored.
>
> For example, eslint lib/* --ext .js will match all files within the lib/ directory, regardless of extension.